Python py project imposible instalar build wheel
Buenas soy nuevo en Termux linux y me gustaria clonar un repositorio de github, pero veo que hay un cierto bug en los foros de termux en los cuales una de las soluciones es la de la imagen, pero desconozco como o que pasos seguir, me pueden apoyar diciendome que debo de hacer o que debo de poner en termux para arregarlo, muchas gracias.
android 12 / CPU MTK helio G25 / TCL 408 version UI v4.0.VK3E / Model T507J
python version 3.11.9
1.- Descargar Termux
2.- "yes a todo" $ pkg update
3.- "yes a todo"$ pkg upgrade
4.- "yes a todo" $ pkg install python
5.-"yes a todo" $ pkg install git
6.- "yes a todo" $ pkg install rust libjpeg-turbo libcrypt ndk-sysroot clang zlib binutils tur-repo
LDFLAGS="-L${PREFIX}/lib/" CFLAGS="-I${PREFIX}/include/" pip install --upgrade wheel pillow
ERROR siempre en el paso 6
Solucion de termux reddit issue 20039 https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/20039


Hola Nitzsel sd ¿cuál es el problema exactamente? Eso son solo comandos para la terminal con la finalidad de crear una copia de seguridad y luego  modificar el archivo, ¿lo has ejecutado en una?

Puedes por favor añadir a tu pregunta  la salida de i) ``echo "term: $TERMUX_PREFIX" pre:$PREFIX"?  y ii) find "$TERMUX_PREFIX/lib/python3.11" "$PREFIX/lib/python3.11" -name "_sysconfigdata*.py"
